# outlook vsto perform custom send message

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I have an Outlook add-in that adds a custom Send button to the NewMailMessage tab in the Compose inspector window. When clicking on this custom button I want to perform some modifications to the email being sent before actually sending it out. How do I get a hold of the email from the button click event? In older versions than Outlook 2010, I know you can programmatically get the "Send" `CommandBar` button and call `Execute` on it to mimic sending the message. However in 2010 and later versions this method has been deprecated. MSDN suggests to implement the IRibbonExtensibility for Ribbon customizations but do I need to do that for my purpose?

Comment: I found the answer:

<!-- language: c# -->
    if (this.Context is Outlook.Inspector)
    {
        Outlook.Inspector oInsp = this.Context as Outlook.Inspector;
        if (oInsp.CurrentItem is Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem oMail = oInsp.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
            ((Outlook._MailItem)oMail).Send();
        }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer:

```
if (this.Context is Outlook.Inspector)
{
    Outlook.Inspector oInsp = this.Context as Outlook.Inspector;
    if (oInsp.CurrentItem is Outlook.MailItem)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem oMail = oInsp.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
        ((Outlook._MailItem)oMail).Send();
    }
}
```